# Can AWS Amplify autodetection 'not' match a pattern?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I'm using AWS Amplify for my Frontend deployments and use their Branch Autodetection feature to match a pattern.
So all branch names that match this pattern is getting deployed.

Ex: `feature*` pattern will autodetect and deploy a branch with `feature-xyz` name.

However, I want to allow autodetect of all branches **except** the ones having `feature*`.

How can I achieve this?

I tried using `^(?!.*feature).*$`  regex to achieve this but it does not seem to work.